# Acts_as_votable routing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been using the acts_as_votable gem and it works on things such as pictures, comments and events etc. But I'd like the option to also be able to like another user.

Reading the documentation I can do this by adding acts_as_votable and acts_as_voter to the model.

The problem is that I don't know how to adjust my routes to take this into account as it is configured a bit differently to the others.

In development the profile page is shown at localhost:3000/@user.profile_name

The route is `get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: 'profile'.`

Using acts_as_votable the route would normally go as something like:

```
resources :comments do
member do
    put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "commentss#downvote"
  end
end
```

But how would I adjust my existing route to work in a similar way?

If I use

```
resources :profiles, only: :show, as: 'profile' do
    put 'like', on: :member
    put 'dislike', on: :member
end
```

That would work as localhost:3000/profiles/@user.profile_name/like.

And that doesn't work with the following:

```
def like
  @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
  @user.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to profile_path(@user)
end

def dislike
  @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
  @user.unliked_by current_user
  redirect_to profile_path(@user)
end
```

Or my buttons to like / dislike.

```
<%= link_to dislike_profile_path(@user), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Remove Hype
<% end %>

<%= link_to like_profile_path(@user), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs"  do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Hype
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :profiles, only: :show, path: '/' do
  member { put :like, :dislike }
end
```

And your links should be working properly

note: by typing in your browser the path it will be done via get, not put, so it will not be working, but I assume you know this :-)

Comment: That gives me the error`No route matches [PUT] "/profiles/testband/like.testband"`

Comment: my bad, fixed answer, should work now :), it should be `resources :profiles`, other changes are just cosmetic :D

Comment: Thanks thats fixed the routing to work. Only problem is I now get an error with my like method. `undefined method `vote' for nil:NilClass` It highlights the line `@user.liked_by current_user `

Comment: probably you will have to change links to be something like like_profile_path(@user.profile_name), because it provides url with ID, and you are searching by profile_name

Comment: All resolved. I had forgot to update the gem to the newest version. Don't think the older one supported the model being votable and a voter.